# Catching continous disconnects in paho-mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am currently trying to maintain an MQTT connection over mobile data on a mobile gateway using the paho-mqtt library.
Due to the nature of the mobile connection I am sporadically facing disconnects which sometimes last something between 5 to 10 minutes.

```
#MQTT SETUP
mqttc = mqtt.Client("c")
mqttc.connect("<MQTT-BROKER-ADDRESS",1883,15)
mqttc.subscribe("/TOPIC")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
        if rc != 0:
                print "Unexpected MQTT disconnection. Attempting to reconnect."
                try:
                        mqttc.reconnect()
                except socket.error:
                        time.sleep(60)
                        mqttc.reconnect()

mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_disconnect = on_disconnect


mqttc.loop_forever()
```

However, this does not seem to do the trick as I'm facing this error after a few hours:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensorsClient.py", line 28, in <module>
    client.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 700, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 822, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

What are possible solutions to this problem? It seems to me, that the on_disconnect callback does not get called from the try-except block when it should reconnect.

Comment: The library should automatically reconnect as long as you don't set `reconnect_on_failure` to false. The way you have coded this two failures in a row will escape your `try`. You can see how the library does this for you ([here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1779)). Note that Python 2.7 support is not what it once was ([see this comment](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/618#issuecomment-962451824) and [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/618#issuecomment-962451824)).

Comment: @Brits I implemented it this way because the automatic reconnect didn't work as it should, because it timed out while reconnecting throwing the exact same error we can see above.

Upgrading to Python 3 however is not possible because the script is running on a embedded gateway which only supports python 2.7.

Comment: I believe that the issue was introduced [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/commit/4910b785a49b989e150eb11e87f7ca5aad38992a#diff-5c7d4e9f0de6ef3ae4a9e2bd724e12b368839fc3de296be10e2b7a66f0ff5959L1715) (removed the now depreciated `socket.error` from the `except`) so using a previous version might help. Alternatively adding a `while True:` and `try`/`except` around `mqttc.loop_forever()` should work (log exceptions and sleep a while - you may want to break on `KeyboardInterrupt`).